# Unable to find headers from installed platformio library

Tags: library, platformio

I wrote a library that I intend to use in several project and I published it via platform.io's library management system.

https://platformio.org/lib/show/12820/FastLED-SectionManager

This is the first time I've published via platform.io (first time I've published any c++ library). I read over [platform.io's docs on creating a library](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/librarymanager/creating.html) and structured my library accordingly with my headers in the `include` directory and the implementation files in the `src` directory:

[image]

And created the following library.json file:

```
{
  "name": "FastLED-SectionManager",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "A led strip index manager that allows for logical groupings of strip sections.",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:chris-schmitz/FastLED-Section-Manager.git"
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Christopher Schmitz",
      "email": "schmitz.chris@gmail.com",
      "url": "https://light-inspiration.com/"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/chris-schmitz/FastLED-Section-Manager",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "fastled/FastLED": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "frameworks": "*",
  "platforms": "*"
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that when I install the library in a different project via platform.io and try to include a header, the header can't be found:

[image: can't find header]

I double checked in the `pio` directory for the project and I can definitely see the header and implementation files:

[image]

So I'm not sure why platform.io can't find the headers.

I can't quite tell what I'm doing wrong. any ideas?

Comment: your library has a typo in main.cpp ... `want to flip the direction on every other row with the third boolean argument` .... 
  `sectionManager.addRangeToSection(0, 0, 3, true);` .... the boolean is 4th argument

Answer (score 1):

I woke up this morning and looked back at the documentation.

A part I mis-read was this:

> We recommend to use src folder for your C/C++ source files and **include folder for your headers**. You can also have nested sub-folders in src or include.

I had my headers stored in the `lib` folder :facepalm:

I tried to search around in the platformio docs for the explanation of the lib vs include vs src folders (I knew I saw it at one point) but couldn't find it.

I then remembered that I read the purpose of each directory in the Readme files in the project structure itself generated when you create a new platformio project:

[image: readmes]

The gist being:

- `src`: your compiled files, i.e. your `cpp` files

  - It's worth noting that you could just shove all of the files in here and it would work
- `lib`: libraries private to your project/library itself
- `include`: declaration and macro definition files, i.e. your header files

This explains how the header files in the `lib` directory worked in the SectionManager project itself but didn't work when using the SectionManager as an installed library; the `lib` directory is only "visible" local to a project, so when I tried to include the header files from another project they couldn't be found.

So in my SectionManager project I moved the headers to the `include` directory, bumped the version number, and published:

[image: update to lib directory]

Then I switched to my main project that I'm pulling the SectionManager library into, adjusted the dependency version to include the minor bump, updated, and now it works!

[image: works!]

Makes sense, I'm just still getting used to c++ and platform.io.